# How to extract Y, Cb and Cr color components?

Tags: java, colors, rgb, format-conversion

I need to decompose a given colored picture in three separate pictures, so that each color component (Y, Cb, Cr) is stored in one picture like [here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/32/CCD.png).
Maybe has an idea how I could get these three pictures with
separately Y, Cb or Cr color components? With following peace of code I can just read out the file and convert the color model from RGB to YCbCr.

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class SpaceConverter {

    static int [] colorComponentsYCbCr = new int[3];
    static int [] colorComponentsRGB = new int[3];


    public static void getRGBComponents (int color)
    {
        colorComponentsRGB [0] = (color & 0xff);
        colorComponentsRGB [1] = (color & 0x00ff) >> 8;
        colorComponentsRGB [2] = (color & 0x0000ff) >> 16;
    }

    public static void convertYCbCr2RGB(int [] componentsYCbCrToConvert)
    {
        int Y = componentsYCbCrToConvert [0];
        int Cb = componentsYCbCrToConvert [1];
        int Cr = componentsYCbCrToConvert [2];

        colorComponentsRGB = new int [3];
        colorComponentsRGB [0] = (int) (Y                        +   1.402 * (Cr - 128));
        colorComponentsRGB [1] = (int) (Y - 0.34414 * (Cb - 128) - 0.71414 * (Cr - 128));
        colorComponentsRGB [2] = (int) (Y + 1.772   * (Cb - 128));
    }

    public static void convertRGB2YCbCr(int [] componentsRGB)
    {
        int blue = componentsRGB [0];
        int green = componentsRGB [1];
        int red = componentsRGB [2];

        colorComponentsYCbCr [0] = (int) (0.299     *   red + 0.587 * green + 0.114 * blue);
        colorComponentsYCbCr [1] = (int) (128-0.169 *   red-0.331   * green + 0.500 * blue);
        colorComponentsYCbCr [2] = (int) (128+0.500 *   red - 0.419 * green - 0.081 * blue);
    }

    public static void getColoredCrPicture(BufferedImage image)
    {
        File f = null;
        // get width and height
        int width = image.getWidth();
        int height = image.getHeight();     

        for (int y = 0; y<height; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x<width; x++)
            {
                int color = image.getRGB(x, y);
                getRGBComponents(color);
                convertRGB2YCbCr(colorComponentsRGB);

                int Y = colorComponentsYCbCr[0];
                int Cb = colorComponentsYCbCr[1];
                int Cr = colorComponentsYCbCr[2];   
                Y = 0;
                Cb = 0;

                int p = (Y << 24) | (Cb << 16) | (Cr<<8);           
                image.setRGB(x, y, p);
            }
        }
        try
        {
            f = new File("/Users/MAC/Documents/workspace/ColorConverter/src/outputX.jpg");
            ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", f);
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public static void getColoredCbPicture(BufferedImage image)
    {
       File f = null;
       // get width and height
       int width = image.getWidth();
       int height = image.getHeight();

       for (int y = 0; y<height; y++)
       {
           for (int x = 0; x<width; x++)
           {
                int color = image.getRGB(x, y);
                getRGBComponents(color);
                convertRGB2YCbCr(colorComponentsRGB);

                int Y = colorComponentsYCbCr[0];
                int Cb = colorComponentsYCbCr[1];
                int Cr = colorComponentsYCbCr[2];   

                Y = 0;
                Cr = 0;
                int p = (Y << 24) | (Cb<< 16) | (Cr <<8);
                image.setRGB(x, y, p);
           }
        }
        try
        {
           f = new File("/Users/MAC/Documents/workspace/ColorConverter/src/outputCb.jpg");
           ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", f);
           System.out.println("WRITE Status: OK");
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
           System.out.println(e);
        }

    }

    public static BufferedImage loadPicture()
    {
        File f = null;
        BufferedImage img = null;

        // read Image
        try
        {
            f = new File("/Users/MAC/Documents/workspace/ColorConverter/src/VILLA.JPG");
            img = ImageIO.read(f);
            System.out.println("READ Status: OK");
            getColoredCbPicture(img);
        }   
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return img;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        BufferedImage image = null;
        loadPicture();
        getColoredCbPicture(image);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question isn't completely clear.  If I understand you correctly, after calculating the Y, Cb and Cr numbers for each pixel you'd have to then figure out how to convert each channel back into an RGB representation that you could write out as a JPEG.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you are looking to do is take an RGB image, convert it to YCbCr and display each of the three channels in YCbCr  as a separate RGB image.

You already have code that converts from RGB to YCbCr . You will also need code that will do the reverse conversion so you can go from YCbCr  to RGB.

You will want to use this same logic, but actually create three Y'CrCb images: (Y, 0, 0), (0, Cb, 0) and (0, 0, Cr). Then convert each of these three images to RGB. These three images will be an RGB representation of each of the three YCbCr  channels.

Comment: I've edited my code, so that now it has also option to convert YCbCr to RGB. When I start the program it creates a red colored picture for "Cb-picture". I think it's because of `int p = (Y << 24) | (Cb<< 16) | (Cr <<8); image.setRGB(x, y, p);`
Is there any method than works with `YCbCr` components?
E.g. when I after RGB2YCbCr conversation I've `Y=0; Cb=0; Cr=123;  and then set p = (Y << 24) | (Cb<< 16) | (Cr <<8); image.setRGB(x, y, p);` does that not mean, that I just set R=0; G=0; and Blue-component to 123?

Comment: please help! The program is not important for me. I just need these three pictures for Y,Cb and Cr of my picture to talk about JPEG-Standard in my PowerPoint presentation until today evening:(